# VS Code error: Could not find C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error trying to pip install scikit, seaborn, matplotlib, etc.

I've checked the location and these folders don't exist (Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer).

I reinstalled VS Code with no luck. Where and how do I get this vswhere.exe file to debug this and install scikit, matplotlib, seaborn, etc.?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `vswhere.exe` is a utility that comes with Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code, and is used to locate Visual Studio installations on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is likely due to a missing or improperly configured C++ build tools on your system,
which are required for building some Python packages from source.

You can download Microsoft Build Tools for Visual Studio from the [official Microsoft website](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/).
During installation, make sure to select the "C++ build tools" workload